# Whats a good design pattern for class that wraps shader parameter values

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, graphics

I am trying to design a class that would wrap shader parameter in such way that it would enable the user to easily set and get its value without a need to write a tonne of validation code outside of this class implementation.

The problem is that obviously the shader parameter values can be of different types, and whether I use templates or method overloading it results in a lot of messy code that if one was to use this class it would probably not be a very pleasant experience.

Is there some clever design pattern that once implemented would render the usage of said class to be more straightforward? I wouldn't mind if the mechanism was more complex as long as its implementation is not exposed to the user of this class.

Also just to be more clear, this shader parameter class is somewhat abstract in that its purpose is only to store the parameter for easier editing and handling across my code base. It does not interact or have any knowledge about the actual shader.

**Edit 1:**
Here's how I attempted to solve the issue before with templates and why I failed:

My template values were derived from a non template base class that I used to store them in a STL containers, but I have run into issues when retrieving the values and being unable to up cast them back into their template values, another issue was the amount of code needed to set and get the values when using this class implementation

**Edit 2:**

The ideal usage would be :

```
ShaderParameter* param = ShaderParameterCollection.GetParameter("color_param");
ShaderParameterCollection->GetParameter("property_name")->Set(vec3());
ShaderParameterCollection->GetParameter("property_name")->Get(&out);
ShaderParameterCollection->AddParameter("property_name", FLOAT_VEC3, vec3());
```

ShaderParamterCollection is just a storage class that internally uses STL container, does mapping and validation, I already have that one sorted.

Comment: You don't want to use templates nor overloading because _they result in a lot of messy_ (really?). Do you know that you have excluded at once almost all the available solutions?

Comment: I didn't said that I don't want to used them at all, but my that attempts at solving the issue using templates resulted in a more complicated usage, which is what I am trying to avoid. I would love to hear your ideas though, how would you use the tempting here and keep it simple to use ?

Comment: Could you integrate the question with an example of use of such a class? Imagine to have it somehow, you are an user. How would you use it? I cannot figure out what you want exactly.

Comment: I have edited my post, see edit 2 for ideal usage scenario, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about a templated value class ? It's not a particular design pattern but could suit your needs pretty well by encapsulating :

1) your private shader data of different types and their public accessors

2) the validation code to be executed when the data are changing (coded in setters for example)

Comment: Thanks, I have attempted that before, I have updated my question with more info

Answer (score 0):

I would start by replacing the string property names that you currently have with typed keys, for example:

```
ShaderParameterKey<color> color_key("color_param");
ShaderParameterKey<vec3> property_key("property_name");
```

Then your collection methods could take a `ShaderParameterKey<T>` as input and return a `ShaderParameter<T>`. Your usage would look like:

```
ShaderParameter<color>* param = ShaderParameterCollection.GetParameter(color_key);
ShaderParameterCollection->GetParameter(property_key)->Set(vec3());
ShaderParameterCollection->GetParameter(property_key)->Get(&out);
ShaderParameterCollection->AddParameter(property_key, vec3());
```

You no longer need to pass the type (`FLOAT_VEC3`) to `AddParameter` because that is encoded in the key.

I'm not sure what issues you ran into in your previous attempt with the template base class but this solution calls for something similar.